# UseEffect running continuously in React?

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to run a component on initial run i was trying to dispatch the state value to another component

while running useEffect in particular component, useEffect is running continuously
UPDATE:

I am having a dropdown too whenever i change from dropdownthe useEffect runs and set the previous value to state

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
        console.log("Role changing")
        console.log(event.target.value)
        setStates(event.target.value);
        dispatch({
            type: "SettingROLE",
            payload: states
        })
      };
```

```
const { dispatch , state: authState  } = useContext(AuthContext);

    const authMenus = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("menus")) || []

    const [states, setStates] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Inside of header useEffect")
        const roleid = authMenus.roles[0];
        if(roleid) setStates(roleid.role)
        dispatch({
            type: "SettingROLE",
            payload: states
        })
      }, [authMenus.roles , dispatch , states]);
```

I tried to remove the dependency of the useEffect  but then dispatch is not working it does not dispatch the value of state

Comment: `authMenus` will always be different because you parse it from the sessionStorage, so it will always trigger the effect.

Comment: try to remove dispatch from `handleChange` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` runs anytime a value in the dependency array changes. If it's running continuously, it's because a value is changing. Objects are compared by reference, so any value created in the component will have a new reference each time it's rendered.

In this instance, `const authMenus = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("menus")) || []` is going to create a new reference type every time the component renders and that's triggering an infinite loop.

There are a lot of ways to solve the problem depending on what you are wanting to accomplish.

You can parse it outside the component by moving that code above it.

You can add it to its own useEffect like another answer.

You can store it in a `useRef`, so it doesn't trigger a rerender.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

```
const authMenus = useRef(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("menus")) || []);
```

You could also use `useMemo` if you have dependencies that you want to trigger the value to update.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

```
const authMenus = useMemo(() => JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("menus")) || [],[someDependency]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should separate your logic into two `useEffect` hooks :

```
useEffect(() => {
       
        dispatch({
            type: "SettingROLE",
            payload: states
        })
      }, [ dispatch , states]);

useEffect(() => {
       
        const roleid = authMenus.roles[0];
        if(roleid) setStates(roleid.role)
      
      }, [authorMenus]);
```

since you're updating a state that's a dependency which causes an infinite rendering.

Comment: Shouldn't  setStates be added as a dependency instead of authMenu.roles ? or anything that HAS changed needs to be put in the dependency ? I ask this to better understand the dependency flow with useEffect.

Comment: @BARNOWL `setStates` is guaranteed to be a stable reference between renders. Adding it to the dependency array will not cause the effect to run any more or less.

Comment: React might complain if you don't add it and have exhaustive deps enabled.

Comment: So which one should it be `authMenu.roles` or `setStates` setState will eventually become a value derived from authMenus. So wouldn't make sense that `[states, setStates]` should be the dependency and not `authMenus.roles ` ?

Comment: So as i am new into React so should i use two effect or a single? why should i add setState?

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to dispatch on initial run,simply passing [] in dependencies should work!

Also, calling setStates inside useEffect is causing infinite loops!You can move the code except dispatch to outside of useEffect